# Flask "[Errno 32] Broken pipe" when querying data from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm working on a flask project. I connected my Flask app to MySQL database, and got an `[Errno 32] Broken pipe` error message when I try to filter my database query with a date range like this:

```
dataset = Air.query.filter(Air.date>=DateTime(2015,6,21),Air.date<=DateTime(2016,6,22)).all()
```

Querying all the results from the database like this works though:

```
dataset = Air.query.all()
```

Why am I facing this error?